# Pratt & Whitney lathe drill chuck

Tags: drilling

I have an old Pratt & Whitney lathe and I need a drill chuck for the
spindle sleeve. Does anyone know what kind of cone I need? It's definitely not a morse cone, since I already tested it. Since I can only post two images, here are the dimensions of the cone:

smaller diameter: 9.2mm

larger diameter: 12.2mm

length: 57.8mm

There might be some error in measurement.

[image: Lathe]

[image: Conus]

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.lathes.co.uk/pratt&whitney/) Suggests that M1 tapers are standard but there are examples with Jarno tapers.

Your measurements seem closest to Jarno #4 but don't match exactly

[This page](http://littlemachineshop.com/reference/tapers.php) has tables of the common taper sizes so you may be able to deduce it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The Pratt & Whitney Precision Tools catalog says these had a Jarno #4 Taper in the tailstock.
[url]https://archive.org/details/precisiontools00pratrich[/url]